# Re-install X from Ubuntu live

Tags: ubuntu, installation, livecd, x-server

I did a non-sense operation and broke my X-server, period.
The sad fact is that it was late and I did not remember what I removed, I think it was a package with python in its name...
I know that this does not provide useful information, so I'm reinstalling X from the base, do you know how to achieve this from the live cd boot?
I cannot do it from the command line because it keeps flashing and does not get all the keystrokes, just once every two or three attempts.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably just the terminal within the GUI that will have that problem since it's being drawn by the X server. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> are all console based virtual terminals.  The first terminal is probably being used by the X server. You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to stop it's execution, then proceed with the following steps:

Fully remove your X server:

```
sudo apt-get remove x-window-system-core xserver-xorg
```

then reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get install x-window-system-core xserver-xorg
```

Comment: None of the consoles is free of that flickering problem. The recovery mode one is ok though. I did as you said, I looked in the logs and it says "Failed to load the NVIDIA kernel module", I'll Google this...

Comment: what does startx do?

Comment: Startx fails, I found two things: 1) it cannot find my monitor 2) it says "Failed to load the NVIDIA kernel module. I also found some errors on update-manager and update-notifier that seem to need each other, with the latter being broken. That seems to be caused on some python-like lib. That is, the error I made last night :(

Comment: Btw, isn't there a way to mount my "old-Ubuntu" into the live one? I tried mount /dev/sda1 /home/me/mounthere but with no success

Comment: @John: x-window-system-core is the package to install in Ubuntu 6.0 and earlier.  Montecristo should probably install xorg instead.   Also, `startx` is the program that starts xwindows.  Typically it's started during your startup sequence.

Comment: @DaveParillo: `startx` is only used for from-the-commandline starts.  your startup sequence runs `gdm` or another login manager (xdm, kdm, etc), which handles initiating the actual Xserver.

Comment: I know what startx is.

Comment: package `ubuntu-desktop` depends on `xorg` depends on `xserver-xorg` depends on `xserver-xorg-core`.  http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/ubuntu-desktop

Comment: he still hasn't specified the version of Ubuntu regardless.

Comment: ~quack.  Thanks for correction!  I didn't really finish that sentence properly after reading.  @John T.  Sorry, I read you question as 'what does does startx do' & you're trying to get montecristo to tell you the output of startx.  my bad.

Comment: @John T: You are right, but is the procedure to mount a filesystem from live-cd so version dependent? Ubuntu 9.10.